# Using sickcodes/Docker-OSX, how to boot directly into an OS X shell with no display (Xvfb) [HEADLESS], using a custom image?

Tags: docker, macos

With the following command, I tried to boot directly into an OS X shell with no display (Xvfb) [HEADLESS], using the sickcodes/docker-osx:naked docker image with a custom Mojave image.

```
# run your own image headless + SSH
docker run -it \
    --device /dev/kvm \
    -p 50922:10022 \
    -v "${PWD}/mac_hdd_ng.img:/image" \
    sickcodes/docker-osx:naked
```

However it ends up with the following error message:

```
nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'
nohup: failed to run command 'Xvfb': No such file or directory
```

#### Details to reproduce:

The version of the sickcodes/docker-osx:naked docker image is: https://hub.docker.com/layers/docker-osx/sickcodes/docker-osx/naked/images/sha256-ffff65c24b7a1588dd665f07f52a48ef5efb9941c2e2fa07573e66524029ab08

The custom image - mac_hdd_ng.img is generated by running:

```
docker run -it \
--device /dev/kvm \
-p 50922:10022 \
-v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
-e "DISPLAY=${DISPLAY:-:0.0}" \
sickcodes/docker-osx:mojave

sudo find /var/lib/docker -size +10G | grep mac_hdd_ng.img # https://github.com/sickcodes/Docker-OSX#container-creation-examples
```

This [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLezYl77Ll8) provides a detailed example of using sickcodes/docker-osx to run Mac OS X in Docker.

Answer (score 0):

Building and using the Docker Image using https://github.com/sickcodes/Docker-OSX/blob/master/Dockerfile.naked with the following edits solved the issue.

Replace Line 63 in Dockerfile.naked

```
RUN pacman -Syu xorg-server-xvfb wget xterm xorg-xhost xorg-xrandr sshpass --noconfirm \
```

With

```
RUN pacman -Sy xorg-server-xvfb wget xterm xorg-xhost xorg-xrandr sshpass --noconfirm \
```

References:

- https://github.com/sickcodes/Docker-OSX/issues/515
- https://github.com/sickcodes/Docker-OSX/issues/498